# Show that a curve $r(t)$ is a straight line if $r'(t)$ and $r''(t)$ are linearly dependent for all $t$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

Show that a curve $r=r(t)$ of class $C^m \; (m\geq 2)$, where $t$ is arbitrary, is a straight line if $r'(t)$ and $r''(t)$ are linearly dependent for all $t$.

So if $r'$ and $r''$ are linearly dependent, that means that there exists a real number $a$ so that $r'(t)=a\cdot r''(t)$.

If $r$ is parametrised by arc length, we get that $r'(s)=r'(s(t))\cdot s'(t)$, thus we have

$$r''(s)=r''(s(t))\cdot s'(t) + r'(s(t))s''(t)=r''(s)s'(t)+a r''(s)s''(t)$$

From here we have that $r''(s)(1-s'(t)-s''(t))=0$, so by direct integration of $r''(s)=0$ we get that $r(s)=c_1 t+c_2$.

Is my way of proving correct?

Comment: The proportionality factor $a$ could vary along the curve.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis What do you mean by vary along the curve.

Comment: @zermelovac if $\;r=c_1s+c_2\;$ is a solution, then $\;r'=c_1,\,\,r''=0\;$ , so  the relation you wrote in the fourth line cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

Counter example: $r(t) = (1,2,3)$.

Linear dependency:
$$
\lambda_1 \dot{r} + \lambda_2 \ddot{r} =  0 \wedge (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) \ne 0
$$

Comment: So how do I prove the statement then?

Answer (score 2):

$$r''(t)=\lambda(t)r'(t)$$
is equivalent to

$$\frac{x''(t)}{x'(t)}=\frac{y''(t)}{y'(t)}=\frac{z''(t)}{z'(t)}=\lambda(t),$$ or by logarithmic integration

$$C_xx'(t)=C_yy'(t)=C_yy'(t)=\mu(t).$$

Integrating once again,

$$C_xx(t)+C'_x=C_yy(t)+C'_y=C_zz(t)+C'_z=\nu(t).$$

This is the equation of a straight line traversed at speed $\nu'(t)\sqrt{\frac1{C_x^2}+\frac1{C_y^2}+\frac1{C_z^2}}$.

Comment: If I may ask, what are $\mu (t)$ and $\nu(t)$?

Comment: @zermelovac Antiderivatives.

Comment: A little bit more care is needed. What if $x'(t) = 0$ (in at least a point)?

Comment: @AlexM.: boom !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I still don't get how can this be a line. I know that if I have $\frac{x-x_0}{m}=\frac{y-y_0}{n}=\frac{z-z_0}{p}=\lambda$, but on my side I have a function $\nu(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curvature, if $r'(t)=ar''(t)$ then for any t :
$$\kappa(t)=\frac{||r'(t)\times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}=\frac{||r'(t)\times ar'(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}=|a|\frac{||r'(t)\times r'(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}=0$$ so $r(t)$ is a parametrization of a straight line.

Comment: I know that, but we can't use curvature to prove this statement.